# Completing web forms and ingesting the responses with R?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr, xml2

So, here's the current situation:

1. I have 2000+ lines of R code that produces a couple dozen text files. This code runs in under 10 seconds.
2. I then **manually paste** each of these text files into a website, wait ~1 minute for the website's response (they're big text files), then **manually copy and paste** the response into Excel, and finally save them as text files again. ***This takes hours*** and is prone to user error.
3. Another ~600 lines of R code then combines these dozens of text files into a single analysis. This takes a couple of minutes.

I'd like to automate step 2--and I think I'm close, I just can't quite get it to work.  Here's some sample code:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)  

textString <- "C2-Boulder1 37.79927 -119.21545 3408.2 std 3.5 2.78 0.98934 0.0001 2012 ; C2-Boulder1 Be-10 quartz 581428 7934 07KNSTD ;"

url <- "http://hess.ess.washington.edu/math/v3/v3_age_in.html"

balcoForm <- html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]
set_values(balcoForm, summary = "no", text_block = textString)
balcoResults <- submit_form(html_session(url), balcoForm, submit = "text_block")
balcoResults
```

The code runs and every time I've done it "balcoResults" comes back with "Status: 200". Success! *EXCEPT* the file size is 0...

I don't know where the problem is, but my best guess is that the text block isn't getting filled out before the form is submitted.  If I go to the website (http://hess.ess.washington.edu/math/v3/v3_age_in.html) and manually submit an empty form, it produces a blank webpage: pure white, nothing on it.

The problem with this potential explanation (and me fixing the code) is that I don't know why the text block *wouldn't* be filled out.  The results of set_values tells me that "text_block" has 120 characters in it. This is the correct length for textString.  I don't know why these 120 characters wouldn't be pasted into the web form.

An alternative possibility is that R isn't waiting long enough to get a response from the website, but this seems less likely because a single sample (as here) runs quickly and the status code of the response *is* 200.

Yesterday I took the DataCamp course on "Working with Web Data in R." I've explored GET and POST from the httr package, but I don't know how to pick apart the GET response to modify the form and then have POST submit it. I've considered trying the package RSelenium, but according to what I've read, I'd have to download and install a "Selenium Server". This intimidates me, but I could probably do it -- if I was convinced that RSelenium would solve my problem.  When I look on CRAN at the function names in the RSelenium package, it's not clear which ones would help me.  Without firm knowledge for how RSelenium would solve my problem, or even if it would, this seems like a poor return on the time investment required. (But if you guys told me it was the way to go, and which functions to use, I'd be happy to do it.)

I've explored SO for fixes, but none of the posts that I've found have helped. I've looked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30954686/web-scraping-with-r-and-rvest), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46091447/r-form-web-scraping-with-rvest), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33885629/submit-form-with-no-submit-button-in-rvest/38387063#38387063), to list three.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

After two days of thinking, I spotted the problem. I didn't assign the results of set_value function to a variable (if that's the right R terminology).

Here's the corrected code:

```
library(xml2)
library(rvest)  

textString <- "C2-Boulder1 37.79927 -119.21545 3408.2 std 3.5 2.78 0.98934 0.0001 2012 ; C2-Boulder1 Be-10 quartz 581428 7934 07KNSTD ;"

url <- "http://hess.ess.washington.edu/math/v3/v3_age_in.html"

balcoForm <- html_form(read_html(url))[[1]]
balcoForm <- set_values(balcoForm, summary = "no", text_block = textString)
balcoResults <- submit_form(html_session(url), balcoForm, submit = "text_block")
balcoResults
```